# Error:Log already in use?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, server

When we up and run the server, there some cases occurs we could not do `CTRL + C` to gracefully shutdown , we should do `CTRL + Z` then.

Then what happens is , it will shut down temporarily and running instances in the background.

My questions are

1) what should I have to do when such run time exception occurs and start it up again without any error like `"Log already in use ?"` ?

2) Is that doing `CTRL + Z` a good practise or any other ways to solve?

3) what exactly Gracefully shutdown means ? :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What Ctnl+Z does in unix environment is suspend the process. It does not stop it like Cntl+C does. Afterwards you can either make it run in the background (using `bg`command) or in the foreground again (usin `fg`), but in both ways, it is still running.

So clearly Cntl+Z is not a way to stop a server.
Cntl+C is what you can call an ungraceful shutdown. to gracefully shutdown it means to stop it through some command in the server that will do all the necessary cleanups before bringing the server down. It can be done in many ways, depending on your server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . <bold> and if we did ctrl + z to forcefully stop the server since server was not responding due to some runtime exception occurs . What should we have to do to continue back ? </bold>  Because in my case I could not start it up and running easily , it says kind of Log already in use error ? then what I am doing is ps | aus grep <xxx>  then kill the background running instances usning kill -9 <pid> , then I can continue it , but this will break the pipeline sometimes and error in databases. :)

Comment: please correct me if I went wrong since , I am a beginner :) Thank you